# jQuery multiple rows carousel, again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousellite

I need a slider with two rows. Found a solution in jQuery google group.

Works, but wrong. :)
With option "circular: true" scrolled into the void. Posted an example to understand what i mean: http://test.demx.info/carousel/

How do fix it?

Comment: In the source code of the page you provided, `circular: true` isn't defined. Please enable `circular: true`

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392397/two-row-slider-with-horizontal-line-and-vertical-line/14376284#14376284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in jCarousel_Lite. [Here](http://codepad.org/8N0PdqPu) is fixed jCarousel_Lite code as a plain text and [here](http://ge.tt/4R9xjCH) it is, zipped.

If you are curious on what was wrong: author checked for two different conditions if user reached the end of carousel' list - first, when `circular` is `true`, he checked it like this: `if (to <= o.start - v - 1)` and `if (to >= itemLength - v + 1)`. The second check, when `circular` is set to `false`, he checked it like this: `if (to < 0 || to > ((itemLength - v) / o.rows))`. What have i done is just changed `if (to <= o.start - v - 1)` and `if (to >= itemLength - v + 1)` to `if (to < 0)` and `if (to > ((itemLength - v) / o.rows))`. And it works! =)