# Two row slider with horizontal line and vertical line?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working with web development, I done slider with moving of right to left and inside single < Li > but I want to create two row slider with horizontal line and vertical line.

Can you anyone help me to develop.[image]

[image]

as you see below image I want to create

Answer (score 6):

I found a new jquery plugin. You can try this plugin

http://jsabdul.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/multiple-rows-carousel/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me exactly what you mean with "two row slider with horizontal line and vertical line". Basing on the picture I can think of 2 solutions:

1. You use a normal list, but each list contains two items:

   ```
    <ul id="slider">
         <li>
          <span class="row">
           <span class="row_item"><a href="#"><img src="topimage1.jpg"></a></span>
           <span class="row_item"><a href="#"><img src="topimage4.jpg"></a></span>
          </span> 
        </li>
         <li>
          <span class="row">
           <span class="row_item"><a href="#"><img src="topimage2.jpg"></a></span>
           <span class="row_item"><a href="#"><img src="topimage5.jpg"></a></span>
          </span> 
         </li>
         <li>
          <span class="row">
           <span class="row_item"><a href="#"><img src="topimage3.jpg"></a></span>
           <span class="row_item"><a href="#"><img src="topimage6.jpg"></a></span>
          </span> 
         </li>
       </ul>

   .row, .row_item{display:block;}
   ```
2. You use two different lists, both controller by the same set of arrows:

   ```
         <ul id="top_slider">
             <li></li>
         </ul>
         <ul id="bottom_slider">
             <li></li>
         </ul>

    And an example of jquery (I assume you're using some slider plugin with a `moveFOrward()` 
    callback, or similar. If you developed your own, adjust accordingly. ):

    $('#arrow_left').click(function(e){
       $('#top_slider').moveForward();
       $('#bottom_slider').moveForward();
       e.preventDefault();
    });
   ```